# cannot change data when uploading images

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I want when I change data and upload image or not upload image, everything runs normally. All data can be entered without problems. How to fix this?

```
const props = defineProps({
    post: Object,
});

const form = useForm({
    title: props.post.title,
    slug: props.post.slug,
    image: props.post.image,
    body: props.post.body,
});

const urlImage = ref(null);
const imageField = () => {
    return {
        onChange: (event) => {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            form.image = file;
            reader.onload = (event) => {
                urlImage.value = event.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },
        onRemove: () => {
            document.querySelector("#imageInput").value = "";
            form.reset("image");
            urlImage.value = null;
        },
    };
};


const update = () => {
    form.put(route("posts.update", props.post.slug), {
        onSuccess: () => {
            form.reset();
            urlImage.value = null;
        },
        preserveScroll: true,
    });
};
```

Image upload

```
<div class="flex items-center gap-2">
        <label class="w-full">
            <span class="sr-only">Choose image</span>
            <input
                @change="imageField().onChange"
                id="imageInput"
                type="file"
                class="block w-full text-sm border border-gray-100 rounded-full text-slate-500 file:mr-4 file:py-2 file:px-4 file:rounded-full file:border-0 file:text-sm file:font-semibold file:bg-violet-50 file:text-violet-700 hover:file:bg-violet-100 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:rounded-full"
            />
        </label>
        <button
            v-if="urlImage"
            @click="imageField().onRemove"
            type="button"
            class="p-1 transition duration-200 ease-in rounded-full hover:bg-slate-300"
        >
            <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke-width="1.5"
                stroke="currentColor"
                class="w-6 h-6"
            >
                <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                />
            </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
    <img v-if="urlImage" :src="urlImage" class="w-full mt-4 h-80" />
```

[This is when i change data and not upload images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjBLV.png) &
[this is when i change the data and upload the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o4Qn.png)

I want when I change data and upload image or not upload image, everything runs normally. All data can be entered without problems

Answer (score 0):

That's an issue with inertia form. put _method property in form and send a post request

```
const form = useForm({
 _method: 'put',
 title: props.post.title,
 slug: props.post.slug,
 image: props.post.image,
 body: props.post.body,
});



const update = () => {
form.post(route("posts.update", props.post.slug), {
    onSuccess: () => {
        form.reset();
        urlImage.value = null;
    },
    preserveScroll: true,
});
};
```